# Clicking a span element in a class with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click into the Over/Under Section on this Website:
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/curico-unido-o-higgins-CtsLggl6/

The HTML is:

```html
            <li class=" active" style="display: block;"><span class="topleft_corner"></span><span class="topright_corner"></span><strong><span>Over/Under</span></strong></li>
```

I have tried the following:

```html
overunder=browser.find_element_by_link_text('Over/Under')

overunder=wait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Over/Under']")))


overunder=browser.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Over/Under']"))
```

All of these followed by `overunder.click()`

However all result in a `NosuchElementException`.

How can I click this item?
I am trying to access and scrape the Over/Under Websites behind this section.

Comment: There is no such element with the text "Over/Under" when I load the page. This element is present, though. `<a onmousedown="uid(5)._onClick();return false;" title="Over/Under" href=""><span>O/U</span></a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the full xpath and this worked for me:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the page_source of the link you provided using selenium, this is what I get for area you're looking for:

```html
<li class="" style="display: block;"><a onmousedown="uid(5)._onClick();return false;" title="Over/Under" href=""><span>O/U</span></a></li>
```

I used

```py
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Over/Under']").click()
```

which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the element with text **Over/Under**, I see the element with text **O/U**

[image: OverUnder]

To click on the element with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Over/Under'] > span").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Over/Under']/span[text()='O/U']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Over/Under'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Over/Under']/span[text()='O/U']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Over_Under]